# unable to get docker image for wso2 IS 6.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I was using public repo for wso2is i.e wso2/wso2is:5.10.0 however when I try to upgrade to 6.0.0 it does not let me pull the image. Looks like 6.0.0 is not on the public repo. How do I get 6.0.0, do we need to have active subscription to use the private wso2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IS 6.0.0 docker image is available in the wso2 docker registry https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management/install/docker/get-started/. You need to have the wso2 account to get the U2 updated IS 6.0.0 docker image. If you want to build a docker image from an open-source distribution, you can build it locally by providing the product. You can check out this readme for further information. https://github.com/wso2/docker-is/tree/master/dockerfiles/ubuntu/is

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not been pushed to docker hub. You can simply build it using the docker file here[1]

[1]. https://github.com/wso2/docker-is/blob/6.0.x/dockerfiles/ubuntu/is/Dockerfile